# Installing OpenOLAT on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to install `OpenOLAT` on `Ubuntu 14.04` but could not find any help how to install it. I would highly appreciate if someone point me how to install `OpenOLAT` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Thanks

Comment: http://www.openolat.com/fileadmin/adminwiki/SW5zdGFsbGF0aW9u.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You may follow the installion instruction provided under [their manual here](http://www.openolat.com/fileadmin/adminwiki/_START_.html)

To install JRE 8 you need to activate the universe repostory.

Comment: Thanks @kupferdrache for your answer. However, when I run `ls -l downloads/ total 136652 -rw-r--r-- 1 openolat openolat 7843733 Sep 18 10:34 apache-tomcat-8.x.x.tar.gz -rw-r--r-- 1 openolat openolat 46808550 Sep 18 10:34 jre-xuxx-linux-x64.tar.gz -rw-r--r-- 1 openolat openolat 85277009 Sep 10 21:42 openolat_1xx.war` , I'm getting the following error:  `ls: invalid line width: -r--r--`. Any thoughts please.

Comment: That is a problem with ls, shouldn't stop you from installing.

Comment: Could you post the entire ls -l output?